# OpenTsdb: Is Space character allowed in Metric and tag information

Tags: space, opentsdb

I was working with openTsdb and came across with the issue that space character is not allowed in metric, tag(tagk) and even the values(tagv). Is there any way we can add space atleast in the value of tag?

I also referred: http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing/index.html#metrics-and-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed.

As per the [documentation you referred](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing/index.html#metrics-and-tags):

> Only the following characters are allowed: a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9, -, _, ., / or Unicode letters (as per the specification)

I suggest you should use '_' in stead of spaces.

Comment: yeah! So it means it doesn't allow spaces in the tag value also.

Answer (score 3):

As of opentsdb version 2.3 there is support for specifying additional characters to allow via the config variable

```
tsd.core.tag.allow_specialchars = !@#$%^&*()_+{}|: <>?~`-=[]\;',./°
```

http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/configuration.html gives more details