# Does opentsdb accept special characters like degree symbol (°), % or ²

Tags: java, unicode, special-characters, opentsdb

I am posting the temperature value form my java code to `opentsdb`. So in one of the tags I wanted to display the measurement-type like whether the reading is in `°C` or `°F`. So I tried to post the unicode `"\u00b0"` from java, though in the `System.out.println` I am able to see the degree symbol but when I post the `opentsdb` is not accepting the value.

I also read the article where it defines the characters which are accepted by `opentsdb`.(in the `Metrics and Tags section`) and it defines that it accepts `Unicode` letters. but when I try to send the `unicode` of degree it doesn't work.
So does it accept the `unicode` of these characters? How can I send them.
http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rules apply to metric and tag values:

1. Strings are case sensitive, i.e. "Sys.Cpu.User" will be stored separately from "sys.cpu.user"
2. Spaces are not allowed.
3. Only the following characters are allowed: a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9, -, _, ., / or Unicode letters (as per the specification)
   **`But in fact, other than above mentioned characters no other is supported by opentsdb.`**

Answer (score 0):

As of opentsdb version 2.3 there is support for specifying additional characters to allow via the config variable (cross posting from [OpenTsdb: Is Space character allowed in Metric and tag information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935320/opentsdb-is-space-character-allowed-in-metric-and-tag-information/) )

```
tsd.core.tag.allow_specialchars = !@#$%^&*()_+{}|: <>?~`-=[]\;',./°
```

http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/configuration.html gives more details