# Unable to process special characters in openTSDB

Tags: opentsdb

I am posting the temperature value form my java code to opentsdb. So in one of the tags I wanted to display the measurement-type like whether the reading is in °C or °F. So I tried to post the unicode "\u00b0" from java, though in the System.out.println I am able to see the degree symbol but when I post the opentsdb is not accepting the value.

I also read the article where it defines the characters which are accepted by opentsdb.(in the Metrics and Tags section) and it defines that it accepts Unicode letters. but when I try to send the unicode of degree it doesn't work. So does it accept the unicode of these characters? How can I send them. http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/writing.html

is it means that Unicode is allowed but only for supported special characters not for all the special characters??? I am using openTSDB 2.2.0 version.

Comment: This was addressed in opentsdb 2.3 series.  See this Q&A for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935320/opentsdb-is-space-character-allowed-in-metric-and-tag-information/55029773#55029773

Answer (score 0):

The doc says they have to be letters.

```
Character.isLetter('°')
// false
```

This is an "other symbol".

```
Character.getType('°') == Character.OTHER_SYMBOL
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Josh.

So, is it means that other special characters like °,%,# etc. are not possible to process into openTSDB or is there any workaround to do it.

your help is really appreciated...!!!